# Visual proof for problem with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z$ be complex number so that $|z|=1$ and $\arg z = \theta \neq  \pi$. Show that

$$z-1 =\left( i \tan\frac{\theta}{2}\right)(z+1)$$ with an image and with algebra.

I did the proof via algebra in polar form $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ using identity  $ \tan \frac{x}{2}=\frac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}$?

$$ \begin{align}z-1 &=i\left( \frac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)(\cos\theta +1+i\sin\theta) \\ &=i\left( \frac{ \cos\theta +1+i\sin \theta-\cos^2 \theta- \cos \theta-i \sin\theta \cos \theta}{\sin \theta} \right) \\ 
&= \frac{\sin \theta \cos \theta-\sin \theta+i(1-\cos^2 \theta)}{\sin \theta} \\ &=\frac{\sin \theta\cos\theta-\sin \theta+i\sin^2\theta}{\sin \theta} \\
\cos\theta-1+i\sin \theta &=\cos\theta-1+i\sin \theta\end{align}$$
But the trouble is with the visual proof. I don't quite see how the $i \tan (\theta/2)$ changes the direction of the $(z+1)$  "vector"

Comment: The very last equality in your developent is rather trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Draw the unit circle. Draw the diameter from $-1$ to $1$. Draw the lines connecting $z$ to $-1$ and to $+1$. Think of Thales.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes I use it show that both sides are equal and the statement was indeed correct.

Comment: @ELEC Oh, that . Well, that's nice, but you may want to make that clearer as it seems to me that it isn't.

Comment: @ELEC, also check that the idnetity you meant for the tangent is, apparently, with $\;\tan\frac x2\;$ , *not* $\;\frac{\tan x}2\;$

Comment: @Timbuc sarcasm huh? the last equality is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure how visual this unless you are a competent geometer!. The two dotted lines from the origin $O$ to $z-1$ and $z+1$ are angle bisectors (external and internal) of the angle $\theta$. So the angle between them is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. That is the $i$ factor. Because multiplying complex numbers adds their arguments, so multiplication by $i$ rotates $z+1$ anticlockwise through $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

The effect of the $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ is to shrink/expand the length of the line segment from $O$ to $z-1$. The triangle with vertices $z,z+1,O$ is isosceles, so the angle between the dotted lines at $z+1$ is $\frac{\theta}{2}$. So remembering opposite/adjacent we get the factor $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$.

If you can remember the Euclidean geometry conventions and are better at drawings than me, you could but little cross lines in the middle of the line segments from $z$ to $z+1$ and $z$ to $O$ to indicate they are equal, and label the three angles (two at $O$ and one at $z+1$ as $\frac{\theta}{2}$. Then it would just about be a visual proof!